# Why would adding a & cause a move in rust?

Tags: rust, linked-list, smart-pointers

The following compiles:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum List {
    Cons(Rc<RefCell<i32>>, Rc<List>),
    Nil,
}

use std::ops::Deref;
use crate::List::{Cons, Nil};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let value = Rc::new(RefCell::new(5));

    let a = Rc::new(Cons(Rc::clone(&value), Rc::new(Nil)));

    let b = Cons(Rc::new(RefCell::new(3)), Rc::clone(&a));
    let c = Cons(Rc::new(RefCell::new(4)), Rc::clone(&a));
    
    match &b {
        Cons(x,y)=>{//line $
            match y.deref(){
                Cons(t,l)=>{
                    *t.borrow_mut() +=10;
                }
                _=>{}
            }
        }
        _=>{}
    }

    println!("a after = {:?}", a);
    println!("b after = {:?}", b);
    println!("c after = {:?}", c);
}
```

Now, consider this change to line $:

```
//snip
  match &b {
        &Cons(x,y)=>{//a reference was added.
            match y.deref(){
//snip
```

This results in the following error: "error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference"

I am confused. It seems like adding a reference there should PREVENT a move- not cause one!

What is the explanation?

Comment: Because `&` in a pattern dereferences, it "matches away" one reference, just like `Cons` in the pattern matches away this constructor.

Comment: that makes sense. but what do you mean by " just like Cons in the pattern matches away this constructor."

Comment: Well you write `Cons(x, y)` in the pattern and it "removes" that constructor and gives you it's parameters `x` and `y` without being wrapped in `Cons`, it removes the `Cons` constructor.

Comment: A usually helpful link for these cases - https://h2co3.github.io/pattern/

Answer (score 3):

[Match ergonomics](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2005-match-ergonomics.html) were added to Rust to make it easier to match references.

When you write something like this.

```rs
match &b {
    Cons(x, y) => {}
}
```

Rust sees a mismatch between the type of the value `&b` and the type of the pattern `Cons(x, y)`. It automatically converts your match into this.

```rs
match &b {
    &Cons(ref x, ref y) => {} // x is &Rc<RefCell<i32>, y is &Rc<List>
}
```

Essentially, it demotes the bindings from having ownership to referencing. Remember that patterns are subtractive: anything that isn't a binding is taken away from the matched value.

```rs
let x = &Some(3); // x is &Option<i32>
let &x = &Some(3); // x is Option<i32>
let &Some(x) = &Some(3); // x is i32
let &Some(ref x) = &Some(3); // x is &i32

let Some(x) = &Some(3); // x is &i32 using match ergonomics
```

There's more about [the `ref` keyword here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.ref.html).

The one you're confused about is actually the normal one. No match ergonomics happen here since the type of the pattern and value match.

```rs
match &b {
    &Cons(x, y) => {} // x is Rc<RefCell<i32>>, y is Rc<List>
}
```

And since you can't change the value behind a shared reference, this is not allowed unless the type of `x` and `y` are [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html).

Comment: I don't think there is any single change to the Rust language that has generated as many StackOverflow questions as match "ergonomics".